# What is a color bars vector diagram?

Tags: components, datasheet, eeprom, diagram, analysis

I'm reading the datasheet of the "AT7456E". This component is an OSD (so-called "on screen display") used on the flight controller of my drone project.

In [the datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/AT7546.pdf) there was this diagram which I never heard of and have just a slight suspect about.

[image: 75% Color Bars Vector Diagram]

Does someone know more about this diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Colour Bars" is a standard NTSC video test pattern.  Your illustration shows how the colour bar signal would display on a Vectorscope (a specialized oscilliscope that displays phase relationships of an NTSC video signal).

Similar test patterns are used with other video systems.  See Wikipedia under "SMPTE color bars" for more information and pictures of the colour bar test signal.

Comment: thank you very much I had absolutely no clue about this topic :)